# should sql input params be included in WCF Data contract Model?

Tags: wcf, web-services, datacontract

I am working with web service factory in VS2008. When modeling the data contract I have members for each column of a sql stored proc, but should members for the sql input parameters be included in the data contract model as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 DataContracts, 1 for the request to the service and 1 for the response from the service (which you already seem to have).

Comment: I have been referencing Mike Liu's 2008 book "WCF Multi-tier Services Development with LINQ". In it he outlines an example with a single data contract and in the service contract 1 or more operation with a request message and response message for each. I have 2 messages in the service contract for request and response on a single operation, but only 1 data contract. My question then is, on the "data contract", I included data members for each column name in the SQL result set, but do I need to include members in it to represent the sproc input params as well? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused by "I have 2 messages in the service contract for request and response on a single operation, but only 1 data contract."  Could you post a snippet from your service contract?  Thanks!